# Invoke-Command Cannot Bind Argument Error

Tags: powershell, invoke-command

Is Invoke-Command not pulling my variables?

Im caught on this one. I could use an xtra set of eyes!

Im pulling services from a remote machine and assigning them by number then passing a stop / start to the remote machine based off user input. Im getting a argument on my variable.

Please forgive the code setup Im new and I write then I clean. Some services and names have been removed for privacy.

Code::

```
$prepend = "ssssssssss"
$append = "sss"
$Fprepend = "tttttttt"
$Fappend = "tt"
$sitenumber = Read-Host 'What is the site number? ex. 1111'
 $name = $prepend + $sitenumber + $append  
 $Fname = $Fname = $Fprepend + $sitenumber + $Fappend

      $global:i=0
Get-service -Name Service,Instance,Server,Integration,Data,Message,FTP,Provider -ComputerName $name |
Select @{Name="Item";Expression={$global:i++;$global:i}},Name -OutVariable menu | Format-Table -AutoSize

$r = Read-Host "Select a service to restart by number"
$svc = $menu | where {$_.item -eq $r}

Write-Host "Restarting $($svc.name)" -ForegroundColor Green

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Fname -ScriptBlock {Stop-Service -Name $svc.name -Force}
 sleep 3
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Fname -ScriptBlock {Start-Service -Name $svc.name -Force}
Get-service -Name $svc.name -Computername $name
```

Error::

Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Stop-Service], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StopServiceCommand

Cannot bind argument to parameter 'Name' because it is null.
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Start-Service], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationErrorNullNotAllowed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand

Comment: No, `Invoke-Command` does not remote variables (the dynamic nature of scripts means it would be really hard to know which ones to remote in general) so there is no variable `$svc` on the remote end when the scriptblock is passed. From 3.0 onwards, you can fix this with `$using`. See [`about_Remote_Variables`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/about/about_Remote_Variables).

Comment: Thanks Jeroen, I passed a -ArgumentList $Service at the end of the Invoke to call my variable. I also wanted to capture the $svc.name into a seperate variable for later use. 
Now it looks like this per line

    $svc = $menu | where {$_item -eq $r}
    $Service = $svc.name 
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Fname -ScriptBlock {Start-Service -Name $args[0]} -ArgumentList $Service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have modified the code and now its working fine.
The issue what you are facing is because inside the script block , **$svc** is not holding any value because its not in the scope even. To make it within the scope you have to pass as an **ArgumentList** and it has to be initiated inside the block as **param**.  Thats why ou are getting as *Null*

Use the below code. I just modified the Invoke part

```
$prepend = "ssssssssss"
$append = "sss"
$Fprepend = "tttttttt"
$Fappend = "tt"
$sitenumber = Read-Host 'What is the site number? ex. 1111'
 $name = $prepend + $sitenumber + $append  
 $Fname = $Fname = $Fprepend + $sitenumber + $Fappend

      $global:i=0
Get-service -Name Service,Instance,Server,Integration,Data,Message,FTP,Provider -ComputerName $name |
Select @{Name="Item";Expression={$global:i++;$global:i}},Name -OutVariable menu | Format-Table -AutoSize

$r = Read-Host "Select a service to restart by number"
$svc = $menu | where {$_.item -eq $r}

Write-Host "Restarting $($svc.name)" -ForegroundColor Green
# You have to pass the $svc as an argumentlist and the same has to be initiated as param inside the script block.
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Fname -ScriptBlock {param($svc)Stop-Service -Name $svc.name -Force} -ArgumentList $svc
 sleep 3
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Fname -ScriptBlock {param($svc)Start-Service -Name $svc.name -Force} -ArgumentList $svc
Get-service -Name $svc.name -Computername $name
```

Hope you understand the issue now.

Comment: That is exactly what the issue was. I took a break and came back to it and caught that. I appreciate the fresh eyes and answer.

Comment: Thanks @DotSlashCrash. Happy to help you out